# Type error when trying to fetch data Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get data from the database based on request with id `u_id` and `x_id` but I am not getting any data instead getting an error `TypeError: display_data() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'u_id' and 'x_id'` can you help?

`code`

```
def display_data(request, u_id, x_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        widget['data'] = Widget.objects.get(u_id = u_id, x_id = x_id)
        return widget
```

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^display_data/$', views.display_data, name="display_data"),
```

Comment: Add your urls.py that use this function

Comment: @gdef_ Updated the question with urls.py

Comment: @Thor Is `u_id` and `x_id` in some form which you post to this url?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Correct, I am passing the form data in `u_id` and `x_id`

Comment: @Thor POST data is not passed to the view as arguments. You can access them from the QueryDict `request.POST` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get them from the POST data instead.

```
def display_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_id = request.POST.get('u_id')
        x_id = request.POST.get('x_id')
        widget['data'] = Widget.objects.get(u_id=u_id, x_id=x_id)
        return widget
```

Also, you might want to use a form for validation.

If you want to get `u_id` and `x_id` as arguments like you are trying, you need to add them to the url.

```
url(r'^display_data/<int:u_id>/<int:x_id>', views.display_data, name="display_data"),
```

Edit:
Use `filter` instead of `get` if you are getting multiple objects

```
widget['data'] = Widget.objects.filter(u_id=u_id, x_id=x_id)
```

Comment: And what would be the endpoint to test on Postman? how do I pass those arguments in the url?

Comment: Get the data from `request.POST` if you are using a form.

Comment: I am getting this `MultipleObjectsReturned`
`get() returned more than one Widget -- it returned 4!`

Comment: That's a different error. You have multiple widgets with those two fields. Use `.filter` instead of `.get`. But that will return multiple widgets in `widget['data']`. If your question was answered please accept the response as correct

Comment: I am getting `name 'widget' is not defined` after added `.filter`

Comment: Because it's not defined. Check your function and see what is happening. You are using `widget['data'] ` but widget is not a variable yet. Add `widget = {}` before that or simply do `widgets = Widget.objects...` instead. These following issues that you had are easily searched, take the time to analyze your code and search for the errors that you get.

Comment: I am getting this `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'has_header'` I am new to Django and learning it and I did searched for this but didn't get enough information